# restrict pagepilling.js (a jQuery plugin) to only a few sections of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, pagepiling.js

How can I restrict pagepilling.js (a jQuery plugin) to only a few sections of the website and not the entire website

Comment: Do you mean that you want that the user will scroll let's say 4 sections, then he will scroll regular?

Comment: Yeah Exactly. I have a website having 4 sections and want the pagepilling effect only when going from first section to the second and then I want regular scrolling.

Comment: I can offer you a solution but it will works only if you can pass the ability to use mouse wheel to navigate between the slides. Why? Because when the user will scroll up in the second section, the plugin will scroll him to the first section. Savvy?

Comment: Just put it here: http://jsbin.com/polujid/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Oh I now get your point. Thanks for the help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this article of mine](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2015/04/09/how-to-create-a-beautiful-fullscreen-single-scrolling-page-like-huge-inc/) where I explain how to do it in the last section by using the option `pp-scrollable`.

Also check [the docs regarding `pp-scrollable`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js#creating-a-scrollable-section).